# Filer by Dates that Start After a Specific Time - pandas, python

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, filter

I have a large dataset of individuals spanning different timeframes, I need to filter for those that exist only within a specified period; `01-01-2019 - 01-10-2019` for example.

Is there a method in pandas that I can use to filter out individuals that either start after or finish before that period?

For example, in the below dataset I would only want to filter for individuals that have data from `01-01-19 - 01-10-19` concurrently, so just `jim` and `sara` would be kept.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'names':['jim','jim','jim','jim','jim','jim','jim','jim','jim','jim',
                           'bob','bob','bob','bob','bob','bob',
                           'sara','sara','sara','sara','sara','sara','sara','sara','sara','sara'],
                  'dates':['01-01-19','01-02-19','01-03-19','01-04-19','01-05-19','01-06-19','01-07-19','01-08-19','01-09-19','01-10-19',
                           '01-05-19','01-06-19','01-07-19','01-08-19','01-09-19','01-10-19',
                           '01-01-19','01-02-19','01-03-19','01-04-19','01-05-19','01-06-19','01-07-19','01-08-19','01-09-19','01-10-19']})
```

Something along the lines of `dflt = df[(df['dates'] >= "2019-01-01")&(df['Date'] <= "2019-01-10")]` but only `if` data exists for the full time period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the count per names as the indicator of whether all dates exists or not.

```
num_days = (pd.Timestamp('2019-01-10') - pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01')).days + 1
df = df.loc[(df.groupby('names').transform('count') == num_days).dates]
```

#### UPDATE

Your actual data's Date is not unique and not normalized, so you need the unique count instead of the simple count.

```
start = df.Date.min() 
end = df.Date.max()
num_days = (end - start).days + 1

# If start/end is fixed date and not by min/max, 
# add filter to make sure it won't start/end on the wrong dates
# df = df[(df.Date >= start) & (df.Date <= end)]

df = df.loc[df.groupby('ID').Date.transform('nunique') == num_days]
```

Comment: Thanks Emma, this works well in the example but doesn't take into account the actual start and end date, `num_days` could just be replaced with a integer.

Comment: what do you mean by "actual" start/end date?

Comment: The dates in this example could be in any timeframe, it just subtracts 2 dates and provides an integer for number of days. This method could be used could be used simply by replacing `num_days` with `9`. What I am trying to do is filter a dataset between 2 specific dates and only keep the data that has contiguous entries in that timeframe.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, this is a helpful example and I appreciate it. Just not quite what I'm trying to do.

Comment: could you add the dataset that is not working and explain how it is not?  Also please explain whether you are choosing the start-end date or duration of dates and how you are choosing?

Comment: I appreciate that you're thinking about this, it's defiantly non-trivial; a sample of the data can be found here - https://pastebin.com/UeyZ4uZu

Comment: In this example the data spans a 2 month period `2019-01-01 - 2019-02-28`, though the 1st entry `ID-0` doesn't start until `2019-02-13`. My goal is to filter out IDs like that that do not have data for the full time period - `2019-01-01 - 2019-02-28`

Comment: I updated my answer. please check if this is what you are looking for or not.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! When you mention that the Dates are "not normalized" what are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the difference between `end_date` and `start_date` and check if the number of days between `start_date` and `end_date` for each name is equal to the full target value (in your case 10).

As for

> I need to filter for those that exist only within a specified period

you can also calculate `min` and `max` existence days for each name and compare them to `start_date` and `end_date` to filter out those who existed before or after a certain interval: `(df_grouped['dates']['min'] >= start_date) & (df_grouped['dates']['max'] <= end_date)`

See the full code:

```
start_date = '2019-01-01'
end_date = '2019-01-10'

difference_days = (datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d') - datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')).days + 1

df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])

df_grouped = df \
    [(df['dates'] >= start_date) & (df['dates'] <= end_date)] \
    .groupby('names') \
    .agg([min, max, 'count'])

df_grouped = df_grouped \
    [(df_grouped['dates']['min'] >= start_date) & (df_grouped['dates']['max'] <= end_date)] \
    [df_grouped['dates']['count'] == difference_days] \
    .reset_index() \
    [['names']]
df_grouped.columns = df_grouped.columns.get_level_values(0)

df.merge(df_grouped)
```

Output:

```
   names      dates
0    jim 2019-01-01
1    jim 2019-01-02
2    jim 2019-01-03
3    jim 2019-01-04
4    jim 2019-01-05
5    jim 2019-01-06
6    jim 2019-01-07
7    jim 2019-01-08
8    jim 2019-01-09
9    jim 2019-01-10
10  sara 2019-01-01
11  sara 2019-01-02
12  sara 2019-01-03
13  sara 2019-01-04
14  sara 2019-01-05
15  sara 2019-01-06
16  sara 2019-01-07
17  sara 2019-01-08
18  sara 2019-01-09
19  sara 2019-01-10
```

By the way,

> Something along the lines of dflt = df[(df['dates'] >= "2019-01-01")&(df['Date'] <= "2019-10-01")] but only if data exists for the full time period.

`2019-10-01` - is October 1st, not January 10th when the formatting is not specified.

Comment: This is helpful thanks, though what I am trying to do if filter the dataset so that all of the rows that occur between the 2 periods are kept as opposed to a count.

Comment: Oh, right. I've updated the answer. It lacked one merge with the original dataframe to leave only the certain names.