# Check if both start and end date exist in column and filter dataframe - python, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, filter, group-by

I have a dataset containing multiple `IDs`,  and `Targets` that spans a time frame of 2 months, available here - https://pastebin.com/UeyZ4uZu

```
start_date = '01-01-19'
end_date = '02-28-19'
```

I need to filter out any data that does not span that entire timeframe, i.e. there is data on `01-01-19` and there is data on `02-28-19`. There does not need to be data for every day in between. For example in the sample dataset here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'names':['jim','jim','jim','jim','jim','jim','jim','jim','jim',
                           'bob','bob','bob','bob','bob','bob',
                           'sara','sara','sara','sara','sara','sara','sara','sara','sara','sara'],
                  'dates':['01-01-19','01-02-19','01-03-19','01-05-19','01-06-19','01-07-19','01-08-19','01-09-19','01-10-19',
                           '01-05-19','01-06-19','01-07-19','01-08-19','01-09-19','01-10-19',
                           '01-01-19','01-02-19','01-03-19','01-04-19','01-05-19','01-06-19','01-07-19','01-08-19','01-09-19','01-10-19']})
```

`jim` and `sara` would be kept, even though `jim` is missing `01-04-19` and `bob` would be dropped as he does not have data for `01-01-19`. I previously asked a similar question here: [Filer by Dates that Start After a Specific Time - pandas, python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76689751/filer-by-dates-that-start-after-a-specific-time-pandas-python/76690135?noredirect=1#comment135210303_76690135), and got the solution:

```
start = df.Date.min() 
end = df.Date.max()
num_days = (end - start).days + 1

# If start/end is fixed date and not by min/max, 
# add filter to make sure it won't start/end on the wrong dates
# df = df[(df.Date >= start) & (df.Date <= end)]

df = df.loc[df.groupby('ID').Date.transform('nunique') == num_days]
```

Which was correct per the question asked but I realized is filtering out additional data that I need to keep. The primary goal is to keep data that exists between the `start_date` and `end_date` and throw out anything that does not contain those bookends.

Something along the lines of:

```
dfin = df.loc[df.groupby('ID').Date.isin([start_date,end_date])]
```

Comment: None of these have data on 02-28-19?

Comment: You want rows where date is between start date and end date? and to discard the rest?

Comment: You appear to be talking about 2019. Either the dates are within January 2019, or they are initial day-of-month, hard to tell. In their current format you cannot accurately use `<` lessthan to compare dates. Recommend you convert with [.to_timestamp()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_timestamp.html) and/or [ISO-8601](https://xkcd.com/1179), and update the question.

Comment: @Michael Cao, I am referring to the full dataset in the paste bin. It spans 2 months and has multiple target values. The `df` is just a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your actual data has rows with data on the end date, you can use a groupby transform and add columns with the first and last date of each name group and use those columns to filter.

The below example modified the data so that Jim and Sara have data on the end of February:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'names':['jim','jim','jim','jim','jim','jim','jim','jim','jim',
                           'bob','bob','bob','bob','bob','bob',
                           'sara','sara','sara','sara','sara','sara','sara','sara','sara','sara', 'jim', 'sara'],
                  'dates':['01-01-19','01-02-19','01-03-19','01-05-19','01-06-19','01-07-19','01-08-19','01-09-19','01-10-19',
                           '01-05-19','01-06-19','01-07-19','01-08-19','01-09-19','01-10-19',
                           '01-01-19','01-02-19','01-03-19','01-04-19','01-05-19','01-06-19','01-07-19','01-08-19','01-09-19','01-10-19', '02-28-19', '02-28-19']})

df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format = '%m-%d-%y')

df['first_date'] = df.groupby('names')[['dates']].transform('min')
df['last_date'] = df.groupby('names')[['dates']].transform('max')

start_date = '01-01-19'
end_date = '02-28-19'

df2 = df.loc[(df['first_date'] <= start_date) & (df['last_date'] >= end_date)]
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion around the data...